# If A is an n by n matrix with $A^2$ = 0 and $rank A = \frac{n}{2}$ then $Col(A)^\perp = Row(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is an n by n matrix with $A^2 = 0 $ and  $rank A = \frac{n}{2}$ then $Col(A)^\perp = Row(A)$

My attempt:

By rank nullity theorem we get $rankA + nullity A =n$ showing that $rankA = \frac{n}{2}$ and $nullityA = \frac{n}{2}$

By the fundemental theorem of Linear Algebra $ColA^\perp = NullA^T$ and $RowA^\perp = NullA$, we know that $dimRowA^\perp = \frac{n}{2}$ and $dimColA^\perp = \frac{n}{2}$

Since their dimensions are the same size, they will be equal.

Answer (score 1):

Two spaces of the same dimension are not necessarily equal.  But in this case $(\text{Row} A) \subseteq (\text{Col} A)^\perp$ because $A^2 = 0$.  That is, the dot product of row $i$ and column $j$ of $A$ is the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^2$, which is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Let's  start by proving that:**  If $A$ is an $n\times n$ square matrix such that $A^2=0$ and rank $(A)$=Nullity $(A)$, then $Col (A) =Null (A)$.

Clearly, *for any* $x \in Col (A)$, $\exists c_i$'s such that  $x= c_1p_1+c_2p_2+...+c_np_n$, where $p_i$'s are columns of $A$. Multiplying both sides by $A$ gives, $Ax=c_1(Ap_1)+c_2(Ap_2)+...+c_n(Ap_n)=0$ (why?) Because $A^2=A[p_1, p_2, ...,p_n]=0$.  Hence, $x \in  Null (A)$. Thus, $Col (A) \subseteq Null (A) \tag {1}$

For the converse part, assume on the contrary that $Null(A)$ is not a subset of $ Col(A)$, which implies that $\exists y \in Null (A)$ such that $y\notin span (q_1,q_2,...,q_{n/2})$, where $q_i$'s are basis of $Col (A)$. So we conclude that $y,q_1,q_2,...,q_{n/2}$ are linearly independent. By $(1)$, all $q_i$'s are in $Null (A)$. Hence, $dim (Null (A))\ge \frac{n}{2}+1$, which is a contradiction. Hence, we must have $Null (A) \subseteq Col (A)$. **By this and $(1)$, we have established that** $$Null (A) =Col (A)  \tag {2}$$

Now, we are ready to prove that: $Col(A)^\perp = Row(A)$ 
From $(2)$, the result directly follows by taking "perp" on both sides.